# Can we install xcode on low resource macbook?

Tags: macintosh

I have a MacBook air probably an old one. When I try to install they say the requirement is not enough. Is there a way to install XCode in any other way. I am new to MacBook.

Comment: What specifically is the error?  XCode versions depend on specific versions of macOS being installed.

Comment: @MarcWilson issue is I am using a 2014 MacBook and I tried to install XCode from app store and it says not compatible with my MacBook. Is there a way to install XCode on on MacBook.

Comment: The XCode from the MAS won't be compatible with that laptop, because that laptop won't run Sonoma.  You will need to install an older version if you want XCode.